# Switch ESLint Appearance on Atom

Tags: atom-editor, eslint

I have been using ESLint on Atom and the appearance of the linter changed and I have been unable to figure how to switch it back.

The linter now looks like this:

[image: new]

and I would like to restore the old look and feel:

[image: old]

Comment: You need to downgrade the `linter` package back to 1.11.23. Also you would have to lock `linter-eslint` to a version that uses the v1 API.

Comment: @Matt You should repost your comment as an answer.

Comment: @CodeMacabre I am not 100% sure about its validity. If he confirms it works then i will look up the last v1 API version of `linter-eslint` and formulate an answer.